# Change VS Code Debugging Action (Restart Button)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am currently writing a VS Code extension that would run debugging that would do different things based on the command in the Command Palette. However, When the debugging does happen, there is a Restart Button. Is there a way to change the functionality of the restart button?
[image: Restart Button]

More specifically, I have 3 possible commands, A, B and C. When pressing the restart button, it seems to last-used command. Meaning, that if I run the debug with command A and press the restart button, it restarts again and debug with command A again.

However, I want the restart button to run command B no matter what. For example, if I run the debug with command A and press the restart button, I want it to restart and debug with command B instead.

Is this possible, and if so, any ideas / resources that I can look at to make this functionality?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your problem